# Does Kafka support Per record fetching

Tags: apache-kafka

As of **OCTOBER 2019** with **Kafka v2.3.0** and **Zookeeper v3.5.5**

> **SCENARIO:**

Consider below scenario where Consumer can fetch records from a topic based on below assumptions;

1. Fetch is designed in such a way that it can fetch **N** records on 1 shot depending upon fetch per ***capacity in bytes***. This is implemented and provided in the form of configuration parameters like `max.partition.fetch.bytes`.
2. Fetch is designed in such a way that it can fetch **N** records depending upon fetch per ***Number of Records***. So If I set that parameter to 1 , this means that it will fetch 1 records on every fetch attempt. This is what is missing in Kafka right now. This can be due to design paradigm and support for streaming, concurrency, partitioning features etc.

> **QUESTIONS:**

1. Currently is there any way that I can fetch only 1 record per Fetch and work accordingly?
2. My application has requirement for both realtime streaming of records and fetch 1 record per fetch. Can both be achieved using Kafka or will I have to end up using 2 different Messaging system like Kafka + ActiveMQ and so on ?

Please guide me on this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: this property should help you in doing that `Number of Records`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NPM Package **kafkajs** does support and helps you with ***fetch_per_record*** mechanism, below is the sample code to achieve this,

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['192.168.1.172:9092']
})

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' })

const run = async () => {

  await consumer.connect()
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'test', fromBeginning: false })

  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      console.log({
        partition,
        offset: message.offset,
        value: message.value.toString(),
      })
    },
  })
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

In above code you have `eachMessage` method that helps us to achieve this mechanism